# How to name and handle memory management on a function that returns a CFType

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I have a project running on ARC (DTCoreText) and I want to implement a category method on UIFont that returns a matching CTFontRef. This is what I have so far:

```
@implementation UIFont (DTCoreText)

+ (UIFont *)fontWithCTFont:(CTFontRef)ctFont
{
    NSString *fontName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CTFontCopyName(ctFont, kCTFontPostScriptNameKey);
    CGFloat fontSize = CTFontGetSize(ctFont);
    return [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize];
}

- (CTFontRef)CTFont
{
    CTFontRef newFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)self.fontName, self.pointSize, NULL);

    return newFont;
}

@end
```

Technically this returns a +1 reference since there is no autoreleasing CF objects.

In my code I am calling it like this:

```
- (void)replaceFont:(UIFont *)font inRange:(NSRange)range
{
    [self beginEditing];

    [self removeAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName range:range];

    CTFontRef ctFont = [font CTFont];
    [self addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName value:CFBridgingRelease(ctFont) range:range];

    [self endEditing];
}
```

This goes without Analyze warning because of the CFBridgingRelease, but I am worried about the need for that not being clear to somebody from the name of the category method.

A different suggestion has been to use a C-function for the creation instead:

```
static CTFontRef CTFontCreateFromUIFont(UIFont *font)
```

That would be more obvious because of the *Create* in the name which tells the developer that he is getting a +1 reference.

So what is the "correct" way in your opinion? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to name the method something like `createCTFont`. I don't know whether the analyzer will consider that to imply CF's Create rule on a method; if it doesn't, you can add an annotation to explicitly declare that the method returns an ownership:

```
- (CTFontRef) createCTFont CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

Naming the method this way should make the reader suspicious if no release follows the creation message, and the annotation will definitely make the analyzer suspicious in the same circumstance.